# Using mouse wheel and up down keys to navigate images in imagelist

Tags: vb.net

The code given below works fine. The only problem is mouse wheel/keyup cannot be used after the TOP image is displayed, it fills the keyboard buffer. Then I have to wait awhile to use wheel/keydown. Also the images after wheel/keydown goes beyond last image. It should stop at the last image like it stops at the first image. Code courtesy of Geek On Demand.

Private Sub Images_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(increaseCount(count))
    End Sub

```
Private Sub Images_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseWheel
    Try
        If e.Delta > 0 Then
            PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(decreaseCount(count))
        ElseIf e.Delta < 0 Then
            PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(increaseCount(count))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Images_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    Try
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Down Then
            PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(increaseCount(count))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Images_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyUp
    Try
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Up Then
            PictureBox1.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(decreaseCount(count))
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function increaseCount(ByRef count As Integer) As Integer
    count += 1
    If count + 1 > ImageList1.Images.Count Then
        count = 0
    End If
    Return count
End Function

Private Function decreaseCount(ByRef count As Integer) As Integer
    count -= 1
    If count - 1 > ImageList1.Images.Count Then
        count = 0
    End If
    Return count
End Function
```

Comment: Basically a Is Nothing or End Sub has to be added at the end of first image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the decrease count function as :

```
Private Function decreaseCount(ByRef count As Integer) As Integer
 count -= 1
  If count - 1 > ImageList1.Images.Count Or count<0 Then
    count = 0
  End If
 Return count
End Function
```

Comment: Works perfectly and the navigation is much more smoother. If you're interested in continuing one more problem then I can describe it, or else I am posting a new problem adding images. In the UP method, when I reach the first image, it stops there. But on scroll down the images keep rolling beyond the last image.

Comment: Geek FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8893639/cannot-add-images-to-imagelist

Comment: If you could pls answer my query.

Comment: What is the query? The above query of image stops scrolling is solved I guess.

Comment: Geek! Try scrolling up. Scrolling stops at the first image-Good, you cannot scroll beyond this point-Good. Now try scrolling down, scrolling continues without a stop-This is the problem.

Comment: in increaseCount() replace count =0 with count = ImageList1.Images.Count

Comment: It's done! Working! I have ticked my original question as answered.